# Snapping an annotation feature class (anno class)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, feature-class, snapping, annotation

Is there any work around for being able to snap an annotation feature class (non-simple feature type) to the vertex points of another layer en masse?

Similar to how the 'Editing toolbox > snap' tool or 'Data Management > Feature Class > Integrate' tool works for 'simple' feature types.

Comment: Is this for ArcMap?

Comment: yes I am using ArcMap 10.4.1